# Limit the number of rows of autocomplete result , and match strings with starting letters only

Tags: autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete in my project,

```
<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Json file

```
[
         { "value": "Saree", 
         "url": "/collection/saree" },
         { "value": "Lehangas", 
         "url": "/collection/lehangas" },
         { "value": "Dresses", 
         "url": "/collection/dresses" },
         { "value": "Tunics", 
         "url": "/collection/tunics" },
         { "value": "Kurtis", 
         "url": "/collection/kurtis" },
         { "value": "Blouses",
          "url": "/collection/blouses" },
         { "value": "Duppattas",
          "url": "/collection/duppattas" },
          { "value": "Shawls",
          "url": "/collection/shawls" },
          { "value": "Plazos",
          "url": "/collection/plazos" },
          { "value": "Skirts",
          "url": "/collection/skirts" },
          { "value": "Patiala",
          "url": "/collection/patiala" }
]
```

my js file:

```
$( function (){
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: "/static/admin/json/search.json",
  select: function (event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.item.url;
    }

});

});
```

It displays all the results no matter which character i enter. I want the string to be matched according to its first letter and the following letters. And also, i want to limit the number of rows displayed to 10.

So , please some one help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Here I have no idea whether you are getting json data in your js file or not , So In my case json data is available in js file and I am accessing json data in my own way I hope you can manage those things.

JS File

```js
var data = [
         { "value": "Saree", 
         "url": "/collection/saree" },
         { "value": "Lehangas", 
         "url": "/collection/lehangas" },
         { "value": "Dresses", 
         "url": "/collection/dresses" },
         { "value": "Tunics", 
         "url": "/collection/tunics" },
         { "value": "Kurtis", 
         "url": "/collection/kurtis" },
         { "value": "Blouses",
          "url": "/collection/blouses" },
         { "value": "Duppattas",
          "url": "/collection/duppattas" },
          { "value": "Shawls",
          "url": "/collection/shawls" },
          { "value": "Plazos",
          "url": "/collection/plazos" },
          { "value": "Skirts",
          "url": "/collection/skirts" },
          { "value": "Patiala",
          "url": "/collection/patiala" }
]


$( function (){
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){
   var lengthOfSearch= request.term.length;
   var arr = jQuery.map(data, function( element, index ) {
    if(element.value.substr(0,lengthOfSearch).toLowerCase() === request.term.toLowerCase()){
     return  element;
    }
   }); 
   response(arr.slice(0,10));
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
   window.location = ui.item.url;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```